# RESTful urls for restore operation from a trash bin

Tags: rest

I've been implementing a RESTful web service which has these operations:

List articles:

```
GET     /articles
```

Delete articles (which should remove only selected articles to a trash bin):

```
DELETE  /articles
```

List articles in the trash bin:

```
GET     /trash/articles
```

**I have to implement an operation for restoring "articles" from "/trash/articles" back to "/articles".**

And here is the question. Ho do you usually do it? What url do I have to use?

I came up to the 2 ways of doing it. The first is:

```
DELETE  /trash/articles
```

But it feels strange and a user can read it like "delete it permanently, don't restore".

And the second way is

```
PUT     /trash/articles
```

Which is more odd and a user will be confused what this operation does.

I'm new to REST, so please advice how you do it normally. I tried to search in google but I don't know how to ask it right, so I didn't get something useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option could be to use "query params" to define a "complementary action/verb" to cover this "special condition" you have (given that this is not very easily covered by the HTTP verbs). This then could be done for example by:

`PUT /trash/articles?restore=true`

This would make the URI path still complaint with REST guideline (referring to a resource, and not encoding "actions" - like "restore") and would shift the "extra semantics" of what you want to do (which is a very special situation) to the "query parameter". "Query params" are very commonly used for "filtering" resources in REST, not so much for this kind of situation... but maybe this is a reasonable assumption given your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using

```
PUT /restore/articles
```

or

```
PUT /restore/trash/articles
```

Comment: Advantage of 2nd over 1st is that you can maintain many sources from where to restore. If you use only /restore it means restore from every sources and everything.

Comment: Thank you very much Adarsh. That is really helpfull, but I found emgsilva's answer a little bit conscious.

Comment: In a strict REST API, one should avoid to use verbs in ROUTE/URLs. The idea is to use HTTP methods (verbs) on resources to perform certain actions

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but, in my opinion, the best way is to change the resource itself.

For instance:

```xml
<article is_in_trash="true">
    <title>come title</title>
    <body>the article body</body>
    <date>1990-01-01</date>
</article>
```

So, in order to remove the article from Trash, you would simple use PUT an updated version of the article, where `is_in_trash="false"`.