# Does RESTful API captures the need to restore (soft delete)

Tags: api, rest, http

Say I have a collection of items, then to provide create/update/delete/restore features I may need following api:

- POST /collections
- POST /collections/:id
- DELETE /collections/:id
- PUT /collections/:id

Assuming UI only know `:id` for the DELETE and PUT routes, is this the right/usual way to handle soft delete and restore?

PS: To me item update should preferably use PUT, but that make my restore route less intuitive, hence the POST choice. Also see related question: [RESTful Soft Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839114/restful-soft-delete), which doesn't talk about restore.

Comment: Have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156890/restful-urls-for-restore-operation-from-a-trash-bin?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do something like

```
POST /collections/:id/restore
```

Here, we treat "restore" as a sub resource of "collections" resource, instead of an extra action on "collections" resource. Here is an example of similar REST API: https://dev.jamasoftware.com/rest#operation_restoreItems

Comment: The problem is most REST API design docs state that no endpoints should have a verb. HTTP has the verbs not our API...?